# How do you log in to an OpenStack VM during rescue operation?

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I have a CentOS 8 VM with a corrupt filesystem and I want to recover data by rescuing it. I ran `openstack server rescue --password somestring myserver`. However, when I tried to log in to the VM by providing the `somestring` password, I can't log in (it says `login incorrect`). The username I used was `centos`.

I also tried running the rescue using an Ubuntu image by doing `openstack server rescue --image UbuntuImage --password somestring myserver`, and I can't log in through that either with username `ubuntu` and password `somestring`. How do I log in to the VM during the rescue process?

Comment: I have never had to use the `--password` option. If I execute `openstack server rescue --image <IMAGE>` I have a root environment where I don't need a login. Have you tried it without specifying a password?

Answer (score 0):

The safest option is to use a special rescue image like SystemRescueCd[1]  or Finnix[2] which does not prompt for password, I believe you can also use Ubuntu Server or CentOS install ISO since it can act as a rescue livemedia.

It could be that the images you are using are locked down and can only be accessible via ssh-keys, during the rescue mode the original disk will be attached a 2nd disk, and new image is started instead of the old disk, so you should try to ssh to it via the key.

[1] https://www.system-rescue.org/
[2] https://www.finnix.org/